# 554+5.2.0+STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException in IIS SMTP Relay When Scanning to Email from a Sharp MX-M364N

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, smtp, iis-6, microsoft-office-365

I am getting the following error in my Windows Server 2012 R2 - IIS6 - SMTP Relay logs when I send a scan from a Sharp MX-M364N copier:

2018-09-25 20:28:54 40.97.132.2 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 - 0 - - 554+5.2.0+STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;+Failed+to+process+message+due+to+a+permanent+exception+with+message+Cannot+submit+message.

The email is also sent to the BADMAIL folder.

Other information:
My relay authenticates with Office 365.
The credentials to login to Office 365 have been verified as correct.
Other copiers in my organization can connect and relay without a problem.

Any ideas on where to look for answers?
I Googled the error code above and checked Sharp's documentation to see if a specific model might have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found I the **Sender Name:** value **MUST** be set under **System Settings** -> **Image Send Settings** -> **Scan Settings**.

If **Sender Name:** value is blank the email will not send and you will receive the above mentioned error in your SMTP logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost same issue, solved it by adding Send-As permission to the sender account. but if youre using Alias (not account) then add the Alias to the mail account. Somewhere in July-october 2018 Microsoft changed this.

i have this setup: Application sends mail to (as account1@domain.dk) -> postfix -> Postfix relays to Office365 with account (account2@domain.dk) to the Customer.
but this kept failing with the error "Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied"

after i added account1@domain.dk as Send-As permission on account2@domain.dk mailaccount, then my problem were solved.

hope this info helps.

// Usman.dk